# Overlapping Strings

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

A simple challenge: given two or more strings, output all of the substrings that are in each string.

## Rules

- Input is always a comma separated list of strings
- Strings should be outputted from longest to shortest length without duplicates
- Strings should preserve whitespace

## Examples

```
Input: aaa,aa
Output:
aa
a

Input: ababa,aba
Output:
aba
ab
ba
a
b

Input: Hello\, world!, Hello world!
Output:
 world!
world!
 world
 worl
world
orld!
Hello
orld
rld!
ello
 wor
Hell
worl
ell
rld
 wo
ld!
llo
wor
orl
Hel
d!
ll
 w
lo
rl
wo
or
He
el
ld
o
l
r
H
e
d
!
w
```

Comment: Based on your testcases it seems you mean *contiguous* substrings, not just substrings.

Comment: You do not have examples of more than two strings as input.

Comment: In addition why is the input format so strict?  The input format you require seems overly stringent.  If I were to solve this the majority of my code would be an input parser.

Comment: To pile on with What Wizard, `\,` is a pretty non-standard way of saying "don't split on this comma". Why not just take as input a list of strings?

Comment: Also - welcome to PPCG! I didn't notice that this is your first post, and didn't mean to bite your head off! :) You might want to check out the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where people often post their questions first so they can get helpful feedback including the usual sorts of expectations that people have for questions/challenges.

Comment: `Input is always a comma separated list of strings` - does this mean you want to pass the strings as a single string, and then we have to split it into an array, or can we just take the input as a list?

Comment: @WhatWizard Substrings are contiguous by default. Subsequences are not.

Comment: Note that [cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8077#8077) are discouraged. If you **really** want to enforce that, you should make it more explicit in the post (and the reason why you enforce it).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I like the challenge (and was about to post an answer), but it got closed as unclear. Reason for this is already stated above, but: 1. You state more than two strings is an acceptable input, so I would add some test cases for three or more input-strings. 2. "_Input is always a comma separated list of strings_". I would make the I/O flexible, so a list of strings is acceptable as both input and/or output. Splitting by comma distracts from the actual challenge.  3. In your `["Hello, world!", "Hello world!"]` test case you don't have a space as output? Both contain a space..

Comment: Also, as mentioned by @ChasBrown, in the future use the [Sandbox of proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/52210) to perfect your challenge based on feedback before posting it to main. Being new you of course didn't knew this, so no problem. If you fix the issues mentioned in the comments above it should be re-opened in no time. :) Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Also, which characters can appear in the input? Printable ASCII?

Comment: Oops, I posted this and completely forgot about it! I'll rewrite the question so that it is clearer tonight, thank you for the feedback everyone!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
€Œ.»ÃÙéR»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOao5P0Du0@3Hx45uGVQYd2//8fre6RmpOTr6NQnl@Uk6KorgPhI7gQtnosAA)

**Explanation**

```
€Œ         # get the substrings of each
  .»Ã      # reduce by intersection
     Ù     # remove duplicates
      é    # sort by length
       R   # reverse
        »  # join on newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Ẇ€f/QṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZHTWvS9AMf7pz1/3B75P//SolJQKikowBiKAEA)

```
Ẇ€f/QṚ  Main Link
 €      For each string
Ẇ       Get all substrings
   /    Reduce this list of lists by
  f     Filter (intersection)
    Q   Remove duplicates
     Ṛ  Reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8

```
_{@Fm.:d
```

### Explanation

```
        Q  # Implicit input list of 2 strings
    m.:d   # get lists of all substrings of each input string
  @F       # intersection
 {         # deduplicate
_          # reverse
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%7B%40Fm.%3Ad&input=%5B%22ababa%22%2C%22aba%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22aaa%22%2C%22aa%22%5D%0A%5B%22ababa%22%2C%22aba%22%5D%0A%5B%22Hello%2C+world%21%22%2C+%22Hello+world%21%22%5D&debug=0).

Comment: The comment should probably read _"Implicit input list of strings"_, since it can be more than two strings.